# How do I iterate a tables rows and pass a specific cell value to an array when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to allow a user to select table rows with a checkbox, once they select the rows and click on a button I want row id text to be stored in an array.

Here is the HTML code for the table to give you an idea of the structure:

```
<table id="test" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Copy</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>                  
            <td>1</td>
            <td>The Name</td>
            <td>The Location</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                  
            <td>2</td>
            <td>The Name</td>
            <td>The Location</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                  
            <td>3</td>
            <td>The Name</td>
            <td>The Location</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So as you can see there is an ID column and each row has a checkbox for selection.  The concept is that you click on the checkbox to choose the rows you want and that will pass the ID values from the selected rows to an array.

I am half way there but I can't get the checkbox part to work at all.  Here is my javascript code to demonstrate my approach to this.

```
var table = $('#test').not('thead tr'),
    rows = table.find('tr:not(:has(th))').get(),
    ids = [],
    rowcount = rows.length,              
    r,cells,cellcount,c,cell;                         

    //Rows
      for (r = 0; r < rowcount; r++) {
          cells = rows[r].cells;
          cellcount = cells.length;

          var checkbox = $(rows).find(".checkbox");            

          //Cells
          for (c = 0; c < cellcount; c++)
          {                                
              cell = cells[c];                  
              var content = cells[0].innerHTML;

                if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
                    ids.push(content);
                }

          }//cells


          //ids.push(content);
      }//rows

      //This is the button that will grab the array that's been populated by the checkboxes.
       $('#go').on('click', function() {
            console.log(ids);                     
       })
```

Comment: First, your code to find rows should be inside click handler

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is always in the first column

```
//Get all the checked checkboxes
var checkboxes = $('#test tbody input:checked');

//Loop through every checkbox
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
    //         <input>          <td>         <tr>        <td>         
    ids.push(checkboxes[i].parentElement.parentElement.firstChild.innerHTML);
}
```